# Thawte EV code signing?

Tags: code-signing, thawte

I saw while Comodo, Digicert, Symantec have the EV Code Signing certificate, Thawte has only code certificate. Does that mean Thawte code signing certificate offer the same stuff as others' EV code signing certificates?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its funny whenever I tell this to others who talk about thawte or Geotrust. Let me tell why,

In 1999, Verisign acquired Thawte and in 2006 they acquired GeoTrust. In 2010, Symantec acquired Verisign's security business, including Thawte. And finally, Symantec sold their Website Security and PKI business to Digicert. Now you get it ?! haha.

So, you're better off with COMODO, Digicert or GlobalSign. You can see the full list here if you want >

[Microsoft EV Code Signing Certificate Partners](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/dashboard/get-a-code-signing-certificate#span-idstep2buyanewcodesigningcertificatespanspan-idstep2buyanewcodesigningcertificatespanspan-idstep2buyanewcodesigningcertificatespanstep-2-buy-a-new-code-signing-certificate)

Comment: Didn't know the history was so complicated.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different between normal Code Signing Certificate and EV Code Signing Certificate.

EV code signing certificate will give your application credit and reputation. If you want to have Automatic SmartScreen Reputation in windows 10, or sign a driver application in Windows 10, you will need EV Code Signing.

Actually, it doesn't matter on the brand, all of them are safe and reliable, to know all the benefit or EV code Signing, you can check out:

https://www.bisend.com/blog/why-you-need-ev-code-signing-certificate